# Width not spanning entire parent's width after width altering function

Tags: javascript, html, css, width, overflow

In my code you'll notice after the function's finished running the inset div's width does completely span the entire width of its parent container but stays the the initial width (I made it red to clearly show). It doesn't effect the codes current purpose as the text runs right past it's width but it'll ultimately mess with future applications. I want the inset div's width to span the entirety of the its parent container's (#fill) width, while not messing up the function. I'm hoping its a simple fix? Thanks.

```js
var inset = document.getElementById('inset')
var fill = document.getElementById('fill')
var text = 'There was a lamb who had a cow and a farmer was involved and then you make a moo sound and yell BINGO and that is how the song goes.';
var words = text.split(" ")

var i=0
var timer = 5;
var wordTime = (timer/words.length)*1000;
    

var myVar = setInterval(myFunct, wordTime);

function myFunct() {
    if (i == words.length) {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
    else {
        inset.innerHTML += " " + words[i];
    }
    i++
    let outer = fill
    outer.scrollLeft += outer.scrollWidth;
    }
```

```css
#wrapper {
        position:absolute;
        display:flex;
        height:100px;
        width:100%;
        min-width:100%;
        max-width:100%;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        align-items: center;
        text-align:right;
        color:whitesmoke;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 200%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
       
    #fill {
        display:flex;
        width:100%; /*You can make this 100% to have text span across entire containing div */
        height:100%;
        max-width:100%;
        align-items: center;
        overflow:auto;  
    }
    
    #inset {
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding-left:5px;
        min-width: 100%;
        background-color:red;
    }
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
        <div id ='fill'>
            <span id='inset'></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove some useless code like below and add `margin-left:auto;` to span element:

```js
var inset = document.getElementById('inset')
var fill = document.getElementById('fill')
var text = 'There was a lamb who had a cow and a farmer was involved and then you make a moo sound and yell BINGO and that is how the song goes.';
var words = text.split(" ")

var i = 0
var timer = 5;
var wordTime = (timer / words.length) * 1000;


var myVar = setInterval(myFunct, wordTime);

function myFunct() {
  if (i == words.length) {
    clearInterval(myVar);
  } else {
    inset.innerHTML += " " + words[i];
  }
  i++
  let outer = fill
  outer.scrollLeft += outer.scrollWidth;
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  min-width: 100%;
  /*max-width: 100%;*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  /*text-align: right;*/
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 200%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#fill {
  display: flex;
  /*width:100%*/
  min-width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

#inset {
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*min-width: 100%;*/
  padding-left: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left:auto; /* Added */
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='fill'>
    <span id='inset'></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this messes with the direction of the text flow

Comment: @HarperCreek edited, simply add `margin-left:auto;` to inner element

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent, than the `#inset`

```js
var inset = document.getElementById('inset')
var fill = document.getElementById('fill')
var text = 'There was a lamb who had a cow and a farmer was involved and then you make a moo sound and yell BINGO and that is how the song goes.';
var words = text.split(" ")

var i = 0
var timer = 5;
var wordTime = (timer / words.length) * 1000;


var myVar = setInterval(myFunct, wordTime);

function myFunct() {
  if (i == words.length) {
    clearInterval(myVar);
  } else {
    inset.innerHTML += " " + words[i];
  }
  i++
  let outer = fill
  outer.scrollLeft += outer.scrollWidth;
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: right;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 200%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#fill {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  /*You can make this 100% to have text span across entire containing div */
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction:rtl;
}

#inset {
  padding-left: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='fill'>
    <span id='inset'></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixes the insets width problem but messes with the direction of the text. It changed it from right to left to left to right

Comment: @HarperCreek Fixed, added `justify-content: flex-end;` to parent

Comment: That fixes the direction problem but now removes the ability to scroll left to see the overflowed text.

Comment: but if I do direction: rtl instead of justify-content: flex-end it all works out!! Thank you

Comment: @HarperCreek can you please edit this solution so that it is what you exactly need.

Comment: except it now puts the period at the end of the sentence at the very beginning of the text, which is strange but not a huge deal.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inset = document.getElementById('inset')
var fill = document.getElementById('fill')
var text = 'There was a lamb who had a cow and a farmer was involved and then you make a moo sound and yell BINGO and that is how the song goes.';
var words = text.split(" ")

var i = 0
var timer = 5;
var wordTime = (timer / words.length) * 1000;


var myVar = setInterval(myFunct, wordTime);

function myFunct() {
  if (i == words.length) {
    clearInterval(myVar);
  } else {
    inset.innerHTML += " " + words[i];
  }
  i++
  let outer = fill
  outer.scrollLeft += outer.scrollWidth;
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  /* Changed */
  overflow: scroll;
  /* Added */
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: right;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 200%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#fill {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  /*You can make this 100% to have text span across entire containing div */
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

#inset {
  position: absolute;
  /* Added */
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 5px;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='fill'>
    <span id='inset'></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If positioning is not an issue, you can try the solution above.